# How to debug SPFX Web part in visual studio code ?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, debugging, typescript

I am trying to find a way to debug my local SPFx workbench from Visual Studio Code, For this have installed the **"skritt-debugger"** and the **launch.json**
Look Like this

```
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Scratch",
        "type": "skritt-debugger",
        "request": "attach",
        "address": "localhost",
        "port": 5432,
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src/webparts/calander20/Calander20WebPart.ts",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "debugLogLevel": 0,
        "showDebugVariables": false
    }

]
```

On Starting the debugging process it throw some error like this
[image]

Pls Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can install **Debugger for Chrome** extension   in the VS Code and follow the step as described  in Github [Debug SharePoint Framework solutions in Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/debug-in-vscode.md)